C Return Value Conventions (Bool or Err Code)
I get this is probably a loaded question, but in C, is it better practice to return a int with error code, or a "success?" boolean. I notice that "0" for success seems convention in libc, but when working with windows.h, they tend to return "1" on success.
I prefer "0" on success because I can encode different errors,
I know others who prefer "1" because of the boolean cast,
Is there any defined/prefered right way, or is it just random?

Aside from main, there are no formal requirements. And you've identified the advantages of each approach. For the most part, it's personal preference. Just don't mix them in the same library.

Depends how much information you want to convey via your error code. If it is just "failure/success" returning non-zero on success might be beneficial because you can write something like if (func_a() && func_b() && func_c()) { /* Success! */ } and it will both take advantage of the short circuit evaluation for sequential execution till the first failure and will read more natural than a similar construct with inverted logic.

Are you talking about return values from generic functions, or from the main function?

For generic functions, C have had a proper boolean type for 25 years.

Also, the Windows API functions usually either returns a BOOL with the values TRUE or FALSE (indicating success or failure), or a HANDLE which will be NULL on error.

@Someprogrammerdude: Fun fact: On Windows NT 4; checking that bool return with == TRUE often didn't work.

@Joshua For some reason that does not surprise me... :)

So perhaps we shouldn't look at Windows NT for inspiration about how to write modern C in the year 2024. The Windows API was first designed when dinosaurs walked the earth (Cretaceous period) and multi-threading was science fiction. And Unix is from the Jurassic period...

Since this got closed: you might find https://software.codidact.com/ a better place to ask these kind of questions, as it allows the super important and often complex topic of program design. The stance of SO has always been to pretend that program design is something vague and fuzzy and that best practices don't exist, which isn't true. It's far more valuable to learn about proper program design than why some compiler error popped up or finding some bug in a peripheral part of your program.

It all depends on if you are writing some low-level/generic stuff, in which case you can pretty much return anything including data, or if you are writing a high-level API to be used by others.
In case of the latter, there are indeed best design practices which are widely accepted, that go along the lines of this:

The return value of any public function part of a library/API should be reserved for a result code.
Results should be as detailed as possible meaning enum or equivalent with a number of codes per library/API. The result type is typically declared along with the library header.
Ideally all functions part of that same library/API should use that same result type.
Number zero in the enum is most often used to indicate OK/no error.
Each function documents which results it may return.
Consequently, return types that are just bool, 1/0 or null pointers etc are not recommended for such high level code.
Using some global error variable like errno, GetLastError or whatever it may be named is a big no-no. These are known to be very error prone, users forgetting to clear them etc. And they can potentially cause problems during multi-threading, even when access to the global resource is thread-safe in itself.



Is there any defined/preferred right way

No

or is it just random?

No.
0 for success appears whenever nonzero for success would not suffice. Cases:

memcmp() and friends are really three-way comparison functions but in practice are almost always not equal/equal. Some binary comparison functions picked this behavior up: 0 for equal, 1 for nonequal.

Processes return 0 for success and nonzero (most platforms restrict from 1 to 255) for error code. This has carried over to functions that start processes and wait for them to return.

Windows COM functions and Windows Native functions return high bit clear for success and high bit set for error.  In most cases there is only one valid success status which is 0 so people test for it directly (treating an unexpected success status as an error, as they probably should).

Unix system calls return -errno on failure (including functions such as mmap that usually return pointers), and libc stuffs the error in errno and returns -1. In old hand Unix code you see < 0 as tests for error for reasons including this one. Some Unix library functions inherited either the direct system call approach or the libc-system call approach either because they were low level right next to libc-system calls or by picking up the thing as though it were a platform preference.


Most other things resulted in either 0 for failure and 1 for success or 0 for failure and any nonzero for success (a bunch of Windows functions declared to return BOOL did this on older Windows NT versions).
There's enough 0 for success cases lying around that it probably isn't too bad if you used 0 for success somewhere for no good reason. Somebody may well pick a bone with you, but that someone won't be me.
Personal commentary: Question got closed opinion based after I posted this answer. I wrote it to be as non-opinion based as possible assuming the question actually was on topic, and as such there is very little opinion here.

Looking at various skunky libs that have major code rot since the 1970s, 80s or 90s isn't the best idea when determining how to design modern C programs. That includes old skunkware such as the C standard lib, GCC extensions, anything Unix/POSIX or the Windows API. There's also a big difference in design considerations between something very low level like memcpy or something very high level like pthread_create etc.

In short, there's no right way. Let's get a few examples from your references:

Windows' ReadFile function on fileapi.h returns a bool indicating the operation's success. In case of false, GetLastError() will return the error code.
Whilst the read function on libc holds three meanings in the return value: read bytes on success, 0 on EOF and -1 on error, and you'll need to check the errno variable to verify which.

Both started long ago with their limitations and concerns, so don't try to follow their patterns too much. The best thing about these APIs is that they are consistent across different functions.
Good APIs are straightforward to use and hard to misuse, but adaptations can make the code integrate with other libraries or hardware more naturally.
